# Can anyone explain why @Declare and @Set is throwing error while just declare and set are working fine?

Tags: mysql

This is in reference to the question 177 in leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-highest-salary/

The question is about Nth highest salary:
Write a SQL query to get the nth highest salary from the Employee table.

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
+----+--------+
```

For example, given the above Employee table, the nth highest salary where n = 2 is 200. If there is no nth highest salary, then the query should return null.

```
+------------------------+
| getNthHighestSalary(2) |
+------------------------+
| 200                    |
+------------------------+

CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN

set N = N-1;

  RETURN (
   select distinct salary
    from employee
    order by salary desc
    limit N, 1
                     
      
  );
END
```

**Above code is working fine but**

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
set @N = N-1;

  RETURN (
   select distinct salary
    from employee
    order by salary desc
    limit N, 1
                     
      
  );
END
```

**This is not working. Also this code is throwing error:**

```
    CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @S INT;
    set @S = N-1;
    
      RETURN (
       select distinct salary
        from employee
        order by salary desc
        limit N, 1
                         
          
      );
    END
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: *why?* In 2nd code - `@N` and `N` are two different variables. In 3rd code - UDV cannot be declared, and `@S` is not used at all.

Comment: @Akina got it, so should I use limit @N, 1 if I set @N = N-1 ?